# HttpListener performance is very low in ubuntu, but very high in windows

Tags: c#, .net-core, httplistener

dotnet core 3.1
HttpListener

The performance of the same code in ubuntu is very low, only 20% of windows. Why is that?

```
 HttpListener web = new HttpListener();
        web.Prefixes.Add("http://+:" + 88 + "/");
        web.Start();
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world!");

        while (true)
        {
            var context = web.GetContextAsync().Result;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = result.Length;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
                context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                context.Response.Close();
            });

        }
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please don't post images of your code. Code is text, so please add it as text. Screenshots are not useful - the help article explains why. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good example of how to not write scalable code. Use `async` / `await`, don't kick off fire-and-forget threads using `Task.Run`.

Comment: ThreadPool has the same problem

Comment: Is the HTTP listener on ubuntu for a program written in mono?

Comment: @Bit why not exactly? .NET Core is well supported on multiple platforms now.

Comment: Of course `ThreadPool` has the same problem; `Task.Run` uses the thread pool. `async` / `await` is [quite different](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/async). What you have now is code that synchronously waits for a request and then kicks off a thread to synchronously write a response, with any number of these overlapping. This is the classic "one thread per request" model and it's not what you should be basing any benchmarks on.

Comment: But why is there such a big gap between windows and ubuntu performance?